# Is it possible to prove that this algorithm is big Omega $n^2logn$ time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, lower-bounds, upper-bound

Considering the following recursive algorithm:
$ T(n)= T(\frac{n}{2})+c_1(\frac {n}{2})^2+c_2n$.
I was able to prove that this algorithm is $O(n^2 logn)$
I was trying to understand whether it is a tight bound or not, yet I was unable to prove that $ T(n)\in \Omega(n^2logn)$
Is it possible or maybe the algorithm's lower bound is $n^2$ ?
Any assistance would help a lot as I am trying to crack this for a while now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your recurrence can be written as:
$
T(n) = T(n/2) + f(n)
$, where $f(n) \in \Theta(n^2)$.

Then, by [case 3 of the Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms)#Generic_form), you have $T(n)=\Theta(n^2)$. This means that you won't be able to prove a lower bound of $\Omega(n^2 \log n)$.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that, describe your recurrence as summation:

$$T(n)=T(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log n}c_1\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2\times\left(\frac{1}{2^i}\right)+ \sum_{i=0}^{\log n}c_2\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$$
$$=\hspace{4pt}T(1)+\sum_{i=0}^{\log n}c_1\left(\frac{n^2}{2^{2+i}}\right)+ \sum_{i=0}^{\log n}c_2\left(\frac{n}{2^i}\right)$$

$$=\hspace{4pt}T(1)+c_1n^2\sum_{i=0}^{\log n}\left(\frac{1}{2^{2+i}}\right)+ c_2n\sum_{i=0}^{\log n}c_2\left(\frac{1}{2^i}\right)=\Theta(n^2).$$

Answer (score -1):

Your “algorithm” runs in O(log n) time. The function that it calculates is O(n^2).